# Having issues decoding using python

Tags: python, base64

I'm trying to fill a list using a loop of base64 encoded messages

```
for i in range(loop_count):
    temp = raw_input("Enter string: ")
    coded_string.append(temp)
```

It should be storing the inputs into the predefined list I have called

```
coded_string[]
```

But whenever the following string is passed "dGhlcmUNCg==" I get the following error.

```
loop_count = input("Enter the amount of strings you'll enter: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    dGhlcmUNCg==
          ^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: try `coded_string = []` to create an empty list.. A complete minimal exaple of your code would probably help identifying your problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please look through the help pages that tell [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently it is hard for other users to reproduce and help you investigate your problem.

Comment: import base64
import os

coded_string = []
loop_count = input("Number of encoded string: ")

for i in range(loop_count):
    temp = raw_input("Enter string: ")
    coded_string.append(temp)

Comment: Please don't post multi-line Python code in comments. It's almost useless because the indentation gets lost.

Comment: However, you should not be using `input` in Python 2: it evaluates your input, which can do unexpected things (like it's doing here), and it can be a security hole. Just use `raw_input`. Or switch to Python 3.